# java agent fails to start with jib created image for a springboot app. [agent library failed to init: instrument]

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, newrelic, jib

I have a spring-boot project with the following structure

[image]

I am using gradle and using the jib plugin to build my docker image.

jib plugin version:

```
id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '3.1.2'
```

I am using the jib plugin to copy all contents of the newrelic folder into the `/app/libs/newrelic` folder then later setting it as the java agent on line 131.

The problem is when I build this image with jib `'jibDockerBuild'`, the process is successful, the files seem to be copied but when I start start any container from this image, I get an error

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /app/libs/newrelic/newrelic.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

I have tred to look at the files in the container and this path exists and the jar also exists in the directory:

using `docker export -o dump.tar 13a92d2f193d`

then  `tar -tvf dump.tar`

I can see the files in the container :

[image]

Could there be something I am missing in the setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot shows that the size of `/app/libs/newrelic/newrelic.jar` is zero. Check the JAR file on your local filesystem and make sure that you have a valid one.

Comment: Thanks once again Mr. @Chanseok, I lost 2 days with a corrupt file. The extra eyes much appreciated.